Seeking the Best Statistical Test to Establish Cutoff for Filtering False Positive Mutations in NGS Data
I have a program that calls mutations from patient DNA sequences. While the sensitivity of this test is 100%, it generates a large number of false positives (FP).
I have developed a method to identify FP mutations using two parameters. For simplicity, I will explain one of them.
When sequencing DNA, the sequencing machine produces DNA reads. For example:
ATGCATGTCA is a read with 10 bases.

The sequencing machine also provides a Quality Score (Q score) for each base. Q scores are defined logarithmically related to the base calling error probabilities (P):

Q = − 10 log10 P

For example, if a base has a Q score of 30 (Q30), this corresponds to a probability of an incorrect base call 1 in 1000 times.
Mutations are identified when a significant number of bases support the mutation compared to a reference genome. For instance, consider 10 reads where 5 reads support the mutation and 5 reads support the wild type:
ATGCACGTCA
ATGCACGTCA
ATGCACGTCA
ATGCACGTCA
ATGCACGTCA
ATGCATGTCA
ATGCATGTCA
ATGCATGTCA
ATGCATGTCA
I have observed that in true positive (TP) events, the mean Q score for the bases supporting the mutation is very similar to the mean Q score for the bases supporting the wild type. However, in FP events, the mean Q score for the bases supporting the mutation is significantly lower (due to machine errors) than the mean Q score for the bases supporting the reference.
Here is a plot illustrating this observation:

X-axis: Mutation frequency (distribution of reads that support the mutation and reference).
Y-axis: Difference in the mean Q score (REF - ALT).
(Ignore the blue dots).
I need a test that helps me to establish the best cutoff because this is an analysis I Have done with training data so I know which are TP and FP but in real analysis, I will not know this.
I need a test to help establish the best cutoff because this analysis was done with training data where I know which are TP and FP, but in real analysis, I won't have this information.
My approach must be very conservative because I want to minimize the false positives as much as possible. True positives (TP) are very important to us, and we don't want to apply any method that deletes TP.
I found a program that computes a Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test for this specific analysis. This is explained here: GATK Rank Sum Test. This Z score returns a 0 when both means are similar and a lower value when the mean Q score of the reads supporting the ALT is lower. However, this statistical test doesn't work for me. See the next plot:

Some TP events get a very low Z-score, and I don't know why. All events in the plot have at least >1000 reads, meaning that the mean of both groups has at least 500 events. The SD doesn't explain this low Z-score either.

So my question is What is the best statistical test to establish a cutoff and filter out FP mutations?


My approach must be very conservative because I want to minimize the false positives as much as possible.

As you recognize, you could minimize false positives (FP) all the way to 0 if you were to rate all mutations as negative. Then, of course, you would have a large proportion of false negtives (FN). That's obviously not what you want.
At an important level, this isn't just a statistical question. It's a question of the tradeoffs that you are willing to accept between FP and FN. That's based on the relative costs to you of those mis-classifications.
The statistical part of the problem is to develop a model that predicts the probability of a mutation based on the data. As you have "training data where [you] know which are TP and FP," you can use those to develop the probability model.
Then you put together the probability model with your FP/FN tradeoff. Scale the costs of those mis-classifications so that they sum to 1, with the cost of a false-positive classification being c and the cost of a false negative thus (1-c). If you choose c as the probability cutoff value from your model, you minimize your overall cost based on your chosen tradeoff.
This page goes into more detail, with links to reading and some discussion about what happens when your model isn't necessarily the "true" model for which that choice of probability cutoff is optimal. You thus might develop a model that predicts probabilities very well specifically around the value you intend to use for c.
